# Emacs: установка закрывающей скобки на уровне определения функции или класса

Tags: lisp, emacs

К примеру, в классе тест при во вложенной функции скобка не переноситься к её определению. Как добавить данную фичу?

Для авто добавления закрывающей скобки использую electric pair mode;

```
class test{
    fuction helloWorld(){
        echo"hello world";
}

}
```

а нужно:

```
class test{
    fuction helloWorld(){
        echo"hello world";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос не ясен, но рискну предложить установить:

```
electric-indent-mode
```

Answer (score 1):

Пользуйтесь:

```
;; АВТОЗАКРЫТИЕ!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
(electric-pair-mode    1) ;; автозакрытие {},[],() с переводом курсора внутрь скобок
(electric-indent-mode -1) ;; отключить индентацию  electric-indent-mod'ом (default in Emacs-24.4)
(setq electric-pair-pairs '(
                                (?\" . ?\")
                                (?\{ . ?\})
                                (?\< . ?\>)
                            ) )
```